# Finding modulus by composite number

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $p_1$ and $p_2$ are prime numbers, $a,b <p_1p_2$. I need to find $ab \pmod{p_1p_2}$. But for some reason I cant find $ab$, it will be too large number. How can I find it without calculating $ab$? Maybe a formula using modulus by $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can find $c$ and $d$ so $ab \equiv c \mod p_1$ and $ab \equiv d \mod p_2$, you want to find $e$ so $e \equiv c \mod p_1$ and $e \equiv d \mod p_2$.
In fact, you can take $e = c + q p_1$ where $q \equiv (d-c) p_1^{-1} \mod p_2$.

Answer (score 5):

Try the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).  That is, assuming $p_1\neq p_2$, the problem
$$
x \equiv ab \pmod{p_1p_2}
$$
Can be solved by breaking it up into the system of equations
$$
x\equiv [ab]_{p_1} \pmod{p_1}\\
x\equiv [ab]_{p_2} \pmod{p_2}
$$
Where $[ab]_{p_i}$ is the modulus of $ab$ by $p_i$. We find the solution to the first equation to be
$$
x \equiv [ab]_{p_1}p_2[p_2^{-1}]_{p_1} + [ab]_{p_2}p_1[p_1^{-1}]_{p_2} \pmod{p_1p_2}
$$